# UIView oscillating motion

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

How do I accomplish an animation of a UIView (in this case an image view) that mimics the motion of a pendulum? I'd like it to swing from left to right and repeat.

Comment: And what is your question? what did you tried? Where is the code?

Comment: Are you using block based animation? If so there is a reverses option for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    [self.imgview setFrame:CGRectMake(self.imgview.frame.origin.x + 50 ,self.imgview.frame.origin.y, self.imgview.frame.size.width, self.imgview.frame.size.height)];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```